# Is it worth to keep using a hard disk with these errors?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, hardware

I was trying to re-use a hard disk that shows errors, I don't remember if the device was hit or it starts making misreads on his own. The fs is ext3.

There are files recovered using the testdisk utility, and then then idea is to erase the partitions and the recreate and format again marking the bad blocks as unusable via

```
badblocks -v /dev/sdx > list
```

and later

```
fsck -l list /dev/sdx
```

But will this be reliable? I intend to use it as removable-media, not for a system.

The output of dumpe2fs has many entrys like this

```
Group 0: (Blocks 0-32767) csum 0xf720 [ITABLE_ZEROED]

  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-19
  Reserved GDT blocks at 20-1024
  Block bitmap at 1025 (+1025)
  Inode bitmap at 1041 (+1041)
  Inode table at 1057-1568 (+1057)
  1616 free blocks, 6429 free inodes, 359 directories, 3847 unused inodes
```

Full text [here](https://justpaste.it/4ltn1)

Comment: Have you checked SMART values (`smartclt`)?

Comment: Yes, but I think its unreliable info https://justpaste.it/3qm1a

Comment: A modern hard disk will try and remap bad sectors into "spare" parts of the disk.  If you're seeing errors reported by `badblocks` then it normally means the disk is so bad it can't fix itself anymore.  I replace disks like that ASAP.

Comment: @sebasth  Because this device has been like that and can access partially , so the part about "failing in less than 24 hours" its incorrect since it already fail, and I dont know if the smart was enabled before the fail.

Comment: `5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct 0x0033 011 011 050 Pre-fail Always FAILING_NOW 2025`  is a bad sign.  `197 Current_Pending_Sector 0x0032 100 100 000 Old_age Always - 82` is even worse.

Comment: @StephenHarris why the statement 197 is worse?

Comment: It means the disk has discovered bad sectors and can't reallocate them.  It's a sign that the disk has started to fail badly.  It's one of the "replace this disk now, if not sooner" indicators.

Comment: Seems to me like some of these comments could combine nicely into an Answer!

Comment: Not quite, “pending sector” counts the number of unreadable sectors which are waiting to be reallocated. The number of unreallocatable sectors is “offline uncorrectable” (which is updated during offline tests, hence the name). Failing sectors aren’t immediately reallocated, in the hope that the drive will be able to read them again at some point; they are normally only reallocated on writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HDD will make a fine resource for very strong magnets. You might even have fun using the discs itself as a small round mirror with a hole in it.

All other uses (i.e. storing and reading data on it) are strongly disadvised. If the `Current_Pending_Sector` is non-zero, the device is currently starting to fail. Do NOT put any data on it that you still need to recover.